# If no results in table show X, PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query on my site and if there is no results, I'd like to say something else rather than have a blank page...

```
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND County = :county");
    $sth->execute(array(':county' => $county));

    $c = 1;
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        RETURNED DATA GOES HERE
    $c++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sth->execute(array(':county' => $county));
if ($sth->rowCount() == 0) {
   echo 'no rows';
} else {
   while(yada yada yada) { ... }
}
```

Relevant docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 2):

You're counting the results in `$c`, so you can check which value that has by appending your code with this:

```
if($c == 1) { // Counter is stuck at 1
    echo "No results were found.";
}
```

Comment: +1. But you have misprint in your answer - it should be "counting the results in `$c`", not in `$i`.

Comment: @a1ex07 Very sharp! Updated :)

Answer (score -1):

2 possible solution,
execute a SELECT COUNT
execute a fetchall check it and later display the result